# Pandas duplicate rows based on column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, transformation

Given the following dataframe

```
data = [[1, 'Yes','A','No','Yes','No','No','No'],
        [2, 'Yes','A','No','No','Yes','No','No'],
        [3, 'Yes','B','No','No','Yes','No','No'],
        [4, 'No','','','','','',''],
        [5, 'No','','','','','',''],
        [6, 'Yes','C','No','No','Yes','Yes','No'],
        [7, 'Yes','A','No','Yes','No','No','No'],
        [8, 'Yes','A','No','No','Yes','No','No'],
        [9, 'No','','','','','',''],
        [10, 'Yes','B','Yes','Yes','No','No','No']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Cust_ID','OrderMade','OrderType','OrderCategoryA','OrderCategoryB','OrderCategoryC','OrderCategoryD'])


+----+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|    |   Cust_ID | OrderMade   | OrderType   | OrderCategoryA   | OrderCategoryB   | OrderCategoryC   | OrderCategoryD   |
|----+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------|
|  0 |         1 | Yes         | A           | No               | Yes              | No               | No               |
|  1 |         2 | Yes         | A           | No               | No               | Yes              | No               |
|  2 |         3 | Yes         | B           | No               | No               | Yes              | No               |
|  3 |         4 | No          |             |                  |                  |                  |                  |
|  4 |         5 | No          |             |                  |                  |                  |                  |
|  5 |         6 | Yes         | C           | No               | No               | Yes              | Yes              |
|  6 |         7 | Yes         | A           | No               | Yes              | No               | No               |
|  7 |         8 | Yes         | A           | No               | No               | Yes              | No               |
|  8 |         9 | No          |             |                  |                  |                  |                  |
|  9 |        10 | Yes         | B           | Yes              | Yes              | No               | No               |
+----+-----------+-------------+-------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

How can I transform this to make rows based on the `OrderCategory`?

```
+--------+-----------+----------+----------------+
|Cust_ID | OrderMade |OrderType | OrderCategory  |
|--------+-----------+----------+----------------|
|1       |   Yes     |    A     | OrderCategoryB |
|2       |   Yes     |    A     | OrderCategoryC |
|3       |   Yes     |    B     | OrderCategoryC |
|4       |   No      |          |                |
|5       |   No      |          |                |
|6       |   Yes     |    C     | OrderCategoryC |
|6       |   Yes     |    C     | OrderCategoryD |
|7       |   Yes     |    A     | OrderCategoryB |
|8       |   Yes     |    A     | OrderCategoryC |
|9       |   No      |          |                |
|10      |   Yes     |    B     | OrderCategoryA |
|10      |   Yes     |    B     | OrderCategoryB |
+--------+-----------+----------+----------------+
```

I tried to use `crosstab` to start with one `OrderCategory`, and planned to duplicate for each category, but this seems inefficient and I wasn't sure how to proceed to get my desired result...

```
imgCROSS = pd.crosstab(df["Cust_ID"], df["OrderCategoryA"])
```

Returns...

```
OrderCategoryA     No  Yes
Cust_ID                   
1               0   1    0
2               0   1    0
3               0   1    0
4               1   0    0
5               1   0    0
6               0   1    0
7               0   1    0
8               0   1    0
9               1   0    0
10              0   0    1
```

I also thought I could populate a new empty column called `Category` and iterate over each row, populating the appropriate category based on the `Yes/No` value, but this wouldn't work for rows which have multiple categories. Also, the below implementation of this idea returned an empty column.

```
imgRaw["Category"] = ""
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    catA = row["OrderCategoryA"]
    catB = row["OrderCategoryB"]
    catC = row["OrderCategoryC"]
    catD = row["OrderCategoryD"]

    if catA == "Yes":
        row["Category"] = "OrderCategoryA"
    elif catB == "Yes":
        row["Category"] = "OrderCategoryB"
    elif catC == "Yes":
        row["Category"] = "OrderCategoryC"
    elif catD == "Yes":
        row["Category"] = "OrderCategoryD"
```

I know I need to transform the dataframe, probably multiple times before I can get my desired result. Just stuck on how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use pandas in four steps:

```
df_1 = df.set_index(['Cust_ID', 'OrderMade', 'OrderType'])

df_2 = df_1.where((df_1 == "Yes") | (df_1 == "")).rename_axis('OrderCategory', axis=1).stack().reset_index()

df_2['OrderCategory'] = df_2['OrderCategory'].mask(df_2['OrderMade'] == 'No','')

df_2.drop_duplicates().drop(0, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Cust_ID OrderMade OrderType   OrderCategory
0         1       Yes         A  OrderCategoryB
1         2       Yes         A  OrderCategoryC
2         3       Yes         B  OrderCategoryC
3         4        No                          
8         5        No                          
13        6       Yes         C  OrderCategoryC
14        6       Yes         C  OrderCategoryD
15        7       Yes         A  OrderCategoryB
16        8       Yes         A  OrderCategoryC
17        9        No                          
22       10       Yes         B  OrderCategoryA
23       10       Yes         B  OrderCategoryB
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it (I did have to modify your original dataframe so that it only had one OrderCategoryD instead of two... hopefully that was a typo):

```
keep_cols = ['Cust_ID','OrderMade','OrderType']
build = pd.DataFrame()

for col in df.columns:
   if 'OrderCategory' in col:
     cat = col[-1:]                              # Get the category letter
     temp = df.loc[df[col] == 'Yes', keep_cols]  # Get all the rows with a yes in this column
     temp['OrderCategory'] = cat                 # Append a column with the correct letter
     build = build.append(temp)                  # Append that df to our new df

# Once that's done, get all the rows that have a 'No' in the OrderMade column
final = pd.merge(build, df[keep_cols], how='right').sort_values('Cust_ID')
final = final.reset_index().drop(columns=['index'])
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Add another Category Column representing the `'No'`s in `'OrderMade'`

This generalizes the problem and enables us to use a more uniform method.

```
d = df.assign(**{'': df.OrderMade.map({'Yes': 'No', 'No': 'Yes'})})
ids, cat = np.split(d, [3], 1)  # split between 3rd and 4th columns
i, j = np.where(cat.eq('Yes'))

ids.iloc[i].assign(OrderCategory=cat.columns[j])

  Cust_ID OrderMade OrderType   OrderCategory
0       1       Yes         A  OrderCategoryB
1       2       Yes         A  OrderCategoryC
2       3       Yes         B  OrderCategoryC
3       4        No                          
4       5        No                          
5       6       Yes         C  OrderCategoryC
5       6       Yes         C  OrderCategoryD
6       7       Yes         A  OrderCategoryB
7       8       Yes         A  OrderCategoryC
8       9        No                          
9      10       Yes         B  OrderCategoryA
9      10       Yes         B  OrderCategoryB
```

#### `melt`

Adding the column simplifies the melt as well

```
d = df.assign(**{'': df.OrderMade.map({'Yes': 'No', 'No': 'Yes'})})
d.melt(['Cust_ID', 'OrderMade', 'OrderType'], var_name='OrderCategory') \
 .query('value == "Yes"').drop('value', 1).sort_values('Cust_ID')

    Cust_ID OrderMade OrderType   OrderCategory
10        1       Yes         A  OrderCategoryB
21        2       Yes         A  OrderCategoryC
22        3       Yes         B  OrderCategoryC
53        4        No                          
54        5        No                          
25        6       Yes         C  OrderCategoryC
35        6       Yes         C  OrderCategoryD
16        7       Yes         A  OrderCategoryB
27        8       Yes         A  OrderCategoryC
58        9        No                          
9        10       Yes         B  OrderCategoryA
19       10       Yes         B  OrderCategoryB
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the other answer, you want `melt` with a some extra cleaning, and merge:

```
id_cols = ['Cust_ID','OrderMade','OrderType']
new_df = df[df.OrderMade.eq('Yes')].melt(id_vars=id_cols, var_name='OrderCategory')


new_df[new_df['value'].ne('No')]
        .merge(df.loc[df.OrderMade.eq('No'), 
                      ['Cust_ID','OrderMade','OrderType']],
               how='outer')
        .drop('value',axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Cust_ID OrderMade OrderType   OrderCategory
0        10       Yes         B  OrderCategoryA
1        10       Yes         B  OrderCategoryB
2         1       Yes         A  OrderCategoryB
3         7       Yes         A  OrderCategoryB
4         2       Yes         A  OrderCategoryC
5         3       Yes         B  OrderCategoryC
6         6       Yes         C  OrderCategoryC
7         6       Yes         C  OrderCategoryD
8         8       Yes         A  OrderCategoryC
9         4        No                       NaN
10        5        No                       NaN
11        9        No                       NaN
```